# Loop over list of file paths, read in JSON files, insert into MongoDB using Pymongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a file folder of 1000+ json metadata files. I have created a list of the file paths and I'm trying to:

- for each file path, read json file
- pull in only the key value pairs I'm interested in
- store it in a variable or save it in a way that I can insert into
  mongodb using pymongo

I have been successful listing the file paths to a variable and loading ONE json doc (from one file path). The problem is I need to do over a thousand and I get an error when trying to incorporate list of file paths and loop.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import pymongo 
import json 

filename = r"C:\Users\Documents\FileFolder\randomFile.docx.json"
with open(filename, "r", encoding = "utf8") as f:
    json_doc = json.load(f)

new_jsonDoc = dict()

for key in {'Application-Name', 'Author', 'resourceName', 'Line-Count', 'Page-Count', 'Paragraph-Count', 'Word-Count'}:
    new_jsonDoc[key] = json_doc[0][key]
```

Sample output:

```
{'Application-Name': 'Microsoft Office Word',
 'Author': 'Sample, John Q.',
 'Character Count': '166964',
 'Line-Count': '1391',
 'Page-Count': '103',
 'Paragraph-Count': '391',
 'Word-Count': '29291',
 'resourceName': 'randomFile.docx'}
```

Now when I add the loop:

```
for file in list_JsonFiles: # this is list of file paths created by os.walk
# if I do a print(type(file)) here, file type is a string
    with open(file, "r") as f:
    # print(type(file)) = string, print(type(f)) = TextIOWrapper
        json_doc = json.loads(f)
        ### TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper ###
```

How can I get my loop working? Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured the TypeError out:

```
for file in list_JsonFiles:
    with open(file, "r", encoding = "utf8") as f:
        json_doc = json.load(f)
        new_jsonDoc = dict() 
        for key in {'Application-Name', 'Author', 'resourceName', 'Line-Count', 'Page-Count', 'Paragraph-Count', 'Word-Count'}:
            if key in json_doc[0]: 
                new_jsonDoc[key] = json_doc[0][key]
```